# syntax when dealing with arrays? c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to understand a piece of code shown below. I'm having problems with understanding what "array +7" or "array,+3" means. Does it increment the first number in the array by 7/3?

```
int array[8] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128}; 
int *ptr_array[4];
int *dyn_array = malloc(sizof(int)*8);

ptr_array[0] = array;
ptr_array[1] = array +7;
ptr_array[2] = array +3;
ptr_array[3] = dyn_array;
```

Comment: array + 7 == &array[7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array + 7` is a pointer to the eight element of the array, it's equal to `&array[7]`, because `x[y]` is defined as `*(x + y)`.

Answer (score 2):

The name of an array variable, when used as an expression, can decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. So when you declare

```
T a[10];
```

then `a` can decay to the address of `a[0]`. This is in fact used whenever you use subscripting: `a[i]` is identical to `*(a + i)`, which itself uses the rules of pointer arithmetic.

So `a + 7` is the address of the eighth element of the array (which is perhaps one-past-the-end of the array if the array has only seven elements).

Answer (score 0):

`array + 7` means the address of the 8th position of the array. In here array hold the base address. So you can access the 8th element of that array by `*(array+7)` or  `array[7]`.